# Obter informação vinda de uma url utilizando node + express + ejs

Tags: node.js, express.js, ejs

Montei uma url no seguinte formato: `localhost:8080/forgetPassword/id/hash`

Tenho essa renderização de rota:

```
app.get('/forgetPassword', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/forgetPassword');
});
```

Então eu gostaria de direcionar para a url `localhost:8080/forgetPassord` e pegar o restante da url `id/hash` onde farei a validação. Porém, não estou conseguindo achar uma maneira de pegar esses dados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar [`params`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params), que passam para propriedades do `req` esses valores. A sintaxe é:

> `/:nomeDaVariavel` ou seja: `/` + `:` + `nome da variável`

Testa assim:

```
app.get('/forgetPassword',(req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/forgetPassword');
});

app.get('/forgetPassword/:id/:hash', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const hash = req.params.hash;

    // fazer algo com "id" e "hash" e depois o redirect:
    res.redirect('/forgetPassword');
});
```

Comment: Perfeito, valeu!