# Como enviar informações de um formulário html para uma rota? - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, ejs

Sou iniciante em NodeJS e estou responsável por um projeto nessa ferramenta. Estou usando a engine "EJS" para criar as views. Criei um formulário, para enviar as  informações digitadas pelo usuário, para uma rota e nessa rota eu processar as informações e devolver uma resposta para essa página html/ejs, mas não sei como proceder com a implementação. Segue o código abaixo da página html/ejs e o código do arquivo referente às rotas da minha aplicação.

> artwork_1.ejs

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Página de Conversação</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3><%= artwork %></h3>
    <img src="images/IMG01.jpg" alt="Imagem da Obra de Arte 1" title="Obra de Arte 1"></br>

    <div id="divChat">

    </div>

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Pergunte-me" required />
        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

> index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: "Página Inicial" });
});

router.get('/artwork-1', function(req, res){
  res.render('artwork_1', { artwork: "Obra 1" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Queres enviar sem recarregar a página ou pode recarregar a página?

Comment: @Sergio bom, o ideal é que não precisasse recarregar a página, mas se isso não for possível então pode ser recarregando a página sim. Você conhece alguma maneira?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129 A solução com ajax é o que precisas. E depois usar esta solução aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146751/129

Comment: Vou testar as soluções que você  me passou. Obrigado por responder!

Answer (score -4):

> Esta usando o express certo ? utilize o comando npm install -g express -generator ,é um módulo que permite criar uma estrutura básica para o se projeto. Em relação ao código, Refiz o código que respondi a você pois ele não fazia o que você precisava, Agora a mensagem é enviada e retorna uma mensagem. O form do  html:

```
<form method="post" action="/" >
    <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Pergunte-me" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

> adicione essas linhas ao app.js para retornar ao site uma mensagem de confirmação após o envio da mensagem.

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send( 'Foi enviado ');
  });

> no index.js não foi preciso fazer alterações.

[image: O retorno da mensagem]